# Lost LVM boot when power supply died

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS system (running server, no desktop).  A few weeks ago my power supply died, after replacing it the system won't boot any more..  I am not sure which version of CentOS it has, I believe an older version.  I booted from a live CD (centOS 7) and selected rescue but just get a blank screen.  I found that it is using grub2 when I mounted one of the old volumes.

Can I get the boot back or is this system gone?

OS: CentOS 6.9 (final)

running lsblk

```
sda  931.5G disk
sda1  500M part
sad2 931G part
    vg_srv2-lv_root 50G lvm
    vg_srv2-lv_home 873.2G lvm
    vg_srv2-lv_swap 7.9G lvm [swap]
sdb 931.5G disk
    sdb1 500M part
    sdb2 931G part
```

Comment: So, while boot from the any rescue media, what do you see? Show us `lsblk` while running a rescue media. Also, if you found the root volume, you may find the file `/etc/redhat-release` and from it you will know which version it was, exactly.

Comment: So, what's inside `vg_srv2-vl_root`? What was boot, `sda1` (this could be inferred from `/etc/fstab` and, probably, comparing the UUID of file system)?

(*Also, please, copy-paste verbatim.*)

Comment: I am copying all the files off the drive before I mess with it.. gonna take awhile

Comment: Sure. Taking a backup is certainly a step in right direction. The only thing wrong with this is that you should have already had a backup :) But I don't see how this prevents you from seeing the files at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my drive was bad.. though I was able to copy off the files, no installer would run when trying to either rescue the drive or just install CentOS from scratch.. put in a new drive and was able to install..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).